# How to print each array in 2d array vertically in perl

Tags: perl

> I have a 2d perl array and I want to print each array vertically, however, I do not know the > size of the biggest array.  How would I iterate through the matrix?
>
> my @AoA = (
> ["abc", "def", 1, 2, 3],
> ["blah", "blah2", 2],
> ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"],
> );
>
> desired output:
>
> `abc   blah     hello`
> `def   blah2    world`
> `1     2        how`
> `2     null      are`
> `3     null      you`
> `null  null    doing`

Comment: You have changed the output that you require. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to scan your data twice: first to establish the maximum number of items in the columns and the maximum width of an item, and then to actually display the data.

This program demonstrates

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @AoA = (
  ["abc", "def", 1, 2, 3],
  ["blah", "blah2", 2],    
  ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"],
);

my $maxrow;
my $maxwidth;
for my $col (@AoA) {
  my $rows = $#$col;
  $maxrow = $rows unless $maxrow and $maxrow >= $rows;
  for my $item (@$col) {
    my $width = length $item;
    $maxwidth = $width unless $maxwidth and $maxwidth >= $width;
  }
}

for my $row (0 .. $maxrow) {
  my $line = join ' ', map sprintf('%-*s', $maxwidth, $_->[$row] // ''), @AoA;
  print $line, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
abc    blah   hello 
def    blah2  world 
1      2      how   
2             are   
3             you   
              doing?
```

---

**Update**

It is much easier to provide your revised output, as there is no need to calculate the maximum field width.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @AoA = (
  ["abc", "def", 1, 2, 3],
  ["blah", "blah2", 2],    
  ["hello", "world", "how", "are", "you", "doing?"],
);

my $maxrow;
for my $col (@AoA) {
  $maxrow = $#$col unless $maxrow and $maxrow >= $#$col;
}

for my $row (0 .. $maxrow) {
  print join(' ', map $_->[$row] // 'null', @AoA), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
abc blah hello
def blah2 world
1 2 how
2 null are
3 null you
null null doing?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use List::Util qw(max);

# calculate length of longest sub-array
my $n = max map { scalar(@$_) } @AoA;

for (my $i = 0; $i < $n; ++$i) {
    # the inner map{} pulls the $i'th element of each array,
    # replacing it with 'null' if $i is beyond the end;
    # each piece is then joined together with a space inbetween

    print join(' ', map { $i < @$_ ? $_->[$i] : 'null' } @AoA) . "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
abc blah hello
def blah2 world
1 2 how
2 null are
3 null you
null null doing?
```

This is sort of dense and hard to read. You could make it more readable by splitting that `print` line into several lines (one line to create a temporary array of all the `$i`'th elements, another line to join them together, and another line to print the result).